# Immediate rollbacks and edited message

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

When someone makes an immediate (within some time threshold) rollback of *their own edit* should that rollback still appear as *"edited X minutes ago"*?  In such cases, it would seem to be the case the the author has decided that their change was inappropriate and it might be better if the system ignored the edit / rollback with respect to the message.  I.e. reverting back to the previous "edited" message before the original edit (or none if there was not such a message).

For example, in [Detecting whether a PHP variable is a reference / referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4817562/469210) the original question was modified by a user accidentally submitting their answer (and overwriting the question) which was quickly reverted back and an actual answer submitted.

Comment: but, if such edits disappeared completely, then we wouldn't know who unlocked their votes via ninja edits!

Comment: As Jan correctly points out, we need to always know when rollbacks occur, no matter who does them.

Comment: I'm not suggesting the edit disappears, rather that it's inappropriate for the "edit X minutes ago" messages.

Comment: I'm seeing an edit from "@minitech" that appears as "[Edit removed during grace period]".  Does that work in the same way on stackoverflow for normal users?

Answer (score 1):

In the case you describe, the user edited the post twice. Once to make a change and a second time to rollback. Had it been two users, then the second user would show up as the "edited by".

This is an edge case scenario which would be difficult to program for and really wouldn't add any value.

---

I think the system is designed for the more common scenario - a user makes an edit and then another user rolls back that edit because they feel it is invalid. I've seen that and done that dozens of times. I've never seen the scenario you've described, but then again I rarely look at the edit history unless I suspect a problem.

The rollback system can also be used to self-correct a mistake. I've done that a couple times, but very rarely. It wasn't specifically designed to "undo" or "cancel" an edit, but is easily adapted for that purpose.

To accomplish what you are describing would involve one of two things:

1. Jerry-rig the rollback feature to inspect the previous edit and hide itself if it's the same user. Of course, you'd probably want to set some reasonable time limit in there, because if the user made a major edit and it sat for a few days and people responded to it and then the user rolled it back, it might be confusing to future visitors (especially if the rolled back edit was the first edit so the post appears to be unedited).
2. Develop an entirely new feature to "cancel" an edit. This would still suffer from some of the problems above without adequate protection (such as "cancelling" being locked after x number of minutes). Of course... there's the question of what to do with the cancelled edit. Should it still be visible to users in the edit history, or should it be deleted? What should be done with any awarded reputation points? Etc.

In either case, seems like a whole lot of effort for the developers but very little gain for users. A better approach would be to implement UX changes to make instances of mistakes less common, but I think the UX is already pretty good at doing that. I'm sure suggestions would be welcome, though.

Comment: Is it really an edge case?  Surely, "Oops, that edit was not actually intended" is reasonably common?  (I've no statistics on this, but it does not seem too unreasonable).

Comment: @borrible IMO it's not very common. In fact, I don't remember any specific case of this happening.

Comment: @borrible - Even if it was common, there's still no harm done and the additional programming complexity wouldn't really add any value to the site. What problems do you see stemming from this?

Comment: If you are following a question / answer for any reason an indication that it's been edited is something that may well lead you to spend time on it.  In cases where there's an immediate rollback, this is wasted effort.

Comment: ... but more to the point, if someone makes a mistake an immediate tries to undo it, what merit is there to highlighting the mistake?  In cases where there edit is immediate and either (a) only the original author saw the change or (b) a couple of people seeing the front page caught it, I would be tempted to go even further and remove both the edit and rollback - although I feel less strong about that.

Comment: @borrible - see update

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - I think what you say about the rollback being designed for the "more common scenario" makes senses.  I did observe, as commented on the original questions, an edit from a moderator which appears as "[Edit removed during grace period]"; I do not know if that's generally available for users.  Thinking about this with these facts, I do still feel that some "undo"/"oops" (... as appropriate) might be suitable for users.  I'm sure someone can check - the "oops" situation does not seem too extreme to ignore entirely.